# files movement in network file system

Tags: c, linux, nfs

I have around 500 directories and each directory contains about 1000 files. I want to move all these files in a single directory(it will have around 500000 files.). But it takes around 20 minutes to do so. I am using readdir iterator and rename function in C. Is there is any better way to do so? I guess because no. of files in single directory is very large(about 500000), so it is taking long time.

Comment: It looks pretty fast actually, it's like 25000 files per second

Comment: @BlackBear it is around 416 files per second.

Comment: 500 000/(20*60) = 400 files per second

Comment: So it takes 2.5ms to rename a file on average. That's about as fast as it can get with a single disk. Do you know what kind of hardware the server has?

Comment: Depending on the server and the network filesystem, there's a good chance that an operation to access a file name is O(n) (n = number of files in the directory). Therefore it's a relatively common recommendation to keep the number of files in a directory relatively low (10k or so) and create some logical directory structure for larger data stores (directories based on the first few characters in the file name or something like that is a common approach I've seen). Could also be that the network filesystem does some operations synchronously. Hard to know without more details.